# Align text content left and right within the same layer

Tags: text, sketch-app

I am pulling a lot of data from a Word document into Sketch, and would like to know whether its possible to align parts of a text layer both left and right, without having to separate them on individual layers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Everything in the *Alignment*, *Opacity*, and *Blending* sections of the inspector apply to the entire text layer. The rest apply at a character level.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Yes, you can. Just select the target paragraph, then change the alignment or other properties.

But this is not a proper way to maintain your document, since it's very easy to mistakenly apply the text style to the whole text layer.